# SAX parser chokes

Tags: android, xml, http

ALL,

This is a continuation of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333376/restriction-on-sax-parser).

I did some debugging and here are my findings.

First some code:

```
class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    SAXParser parser = spf.newSAXParser();
    XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader();
    ProductXMLParser productParser = new ProductXMLParser();
    reader.setContentHandler( productParser );
    reader.parse( new Communicator().getXML( params, true ) );
}
class Communicator
{   
    public InputSource getXML(List<NameValuePair> params, boolean writeToFile)
{
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost( categories_url );
    InputSource source = null;
    try
    {
        post.setEntity( new UrlEncodedFormEntity( params ) );
        HttpResponse responce = client.execute( post );
        StatusLine status = responce.getStatusLine();
        if( status.getStatusCode() != 200 )
            throw new IOException( "Invalid responce from server: " + status.toString() );
        InputStream is = responce.getEntity().getContent();
        /*if( writeToFile )
        {
            final File file = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "products.txt" );
            if( !file.exists() )
                file.createNewFile();
            final OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream( file );
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int read;
            while( ( read = is.read( buffer ) ) != -1 )
                stream.write( buffer, 0, read );
            stream.flush();
            stream.close();
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader( new FileInputStream( file ) );
            source = new InputSource( reader );
        }
        else*/
            source = new InputSource( is );
    }
    catch( UnsupportedEncodingException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch( IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return source;
}
public Bitmap loadProductPicture(String url) throws IOException
{
    InputStream stream = null;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try
    {
        stream = new URL( url ).openStream();
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream( stream );
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        stream.close();
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

This is the original code I tried. Checking under debugger I see that getStatusCode() returns 200, which means everything is OK, but as explained in the linked thread the parser chokes and throws an exception reading the data somewhere in the resulting stream.

Just to make sure everything is OK, I added writing to a file code (commented out piece above). Trying to run the modified version there is no exception and everything is parsed correctly. I can see the results on the device. My guess is that even though web server returns 200 there is still some data to read in the buffer

Now my question is: How do I check for a situation like this? Or is it a bug on the server side implementation? The xml file I am receiving is not malformed and is complete but going through the file saving routine I see it does going thru the saving loop couple of times. Or maybe there is a parameter I can set to set the http client buffer appropriately?

Thank you for any suggestions.

[EDIT]

```
06-27 11:53:08.702: E/AndroidRuntime(3114): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-27 11:53:08.702: E/AndroidRuntime(3114): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.skylite.irabwah/com.skylite.irabwah.IRabwah}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-27 11:53:08.702: E/AndroidRuntime(3114):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1872)
06-27 11:53:08.702: E/AndroidRuntime(3114):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1893)
06-27 11:53:08.702: E/AndroidRuntime(3114):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-27 11:53:08.702: E/AndroidRuntime(3114):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1054)
06-27 11:53:08.702: E/AndroidRuntime(3114):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-27 11:53:08.702: E/AndroidRuntime(3114):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
06-27 11:53:08.702: E/AndroidRuntime(3114):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
06-27 11:53:08.702: E/AndroidRuntime(3114):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-27 11:53:08.702: E/AndroidRuntime(3114):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-27 11:53:08.702: E/AndroidRuntime(3114):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
06-27 11:53:08.702: E/AndroidRuntime(3114):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
06-27 11:53:08.702: E/AndroidRuntime(3114):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-27 11:53:08.702: E/AndroidRuntime(3114): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-27 11:53:08.702: E/AndroidRuntime(3114):     at com.skylite.irabwah.Communicator.loadProductPicture(Communicator.java:88)
06-27 11:53:08.702: E/AndroidRuntime(3114):     at com.skylite.irabwah.ProductXMLParser.characters(ProductXMLParser.java:168)
06-27 11:53:08.702: E/AndroidRuntime(3114):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.text(ExpatParser.java:165)
06-27 11:53:08.702: E/AndroidRuntime(3114):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.appendBytes(Native Method)
06-27 11:53:08.702: E/AndroidRuntime(3114):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseFragment(ExpatParser.java:518)
06-27 11:53:08.702: E/AndroidRuntime(3114):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:479)
06-27 11:53:08.702: E/AndroidRuntime(3114):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:318)
06-27 11:53:08.702: E/AndroidRuntime(3114):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:275)
06-27 11:53:08.702: E/AndroidRuntime(3114):     at com.skylite.irabwah.IRabwah.onCreate(IRabwah.java:81)
06-27 11:53:08.702: E/AndroidRuntime(3114):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
06-27 11:53:08.702: E/AndroidRuntime(3114):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1836)
06-27 11:53:08.702: E/AndroidRuntime(3114):     ... 11 more

class ProductXMLParser
{
    @Override
    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
    {
        if( inProductPicture )
        {
        Communicator comm = new Communicator();
        try
        {
            Bitmap bmp = comm.loadProductPicture( new String( ch, start, length ) );
        product.setProduct_picture( bmp );
            }
            catch( IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
    }
}
```

[/EDIT]

[EDIT2]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss version="2.0">
<products>
<product>
<product_id>72</product_id>
<cat_id>59</cat_id>
<cat_name>Foods &amp; Meals</cat_name>
<product_code>IR-MI-01</product_code>
<product_name>MITHAI</product_name>
<description>   MITHAI pack contain's Combination of different delicious and delightful sweets such as Gulab jaamun, rass gulla, Barfi, laddu bake in pure desi ghee. Also sugar less sweets variety is available.</description>
<rating>n/a</rating>
<image_url>http://irabwah.com/image/data/1_kg_mithai.jpg</image_url>
<price>4.99</price>
<discount>0</discount>
<stock_status>In Stock</stock_status>
<stock_quantity>1006</stock_quantity>
<weight>0</weight>
<length>n/a</length>
<width>n/a</width>
<height>n/a</height>
<colour>n/a</colour>
<size>n/a</size>
<material>n/a</material>
<pattern>n/a</pattern>
</product>
<product>
<product_id>59</product_id>
<cat_id>59</cat_id>
<cat_name>Foods &amp; Meals</cat_name>
<product_code>IR-PZ-03</product_code>
<product_name>Master Pizza, Nuggets, Fries &amp; Coke</product_name>
<description>   Master Pizza with 5 types of sausage and tasty toppings: Chicken, Chees, Mushroom, Tomato, Onion, Pizza Saus &amp;amp; Sweet Corn, with 6 Chicken Nuggets, Large Fries and 1.5 ltr Coke.</description>
<rating>n/a</rating>
<image_url>http://irabwah.com/image/data/Master_pizza.jpg</image_url>
<price>15.99</price>
<discount>0</discount>
<stock_status>In Stock</stock_status>
<stock_quantity>1001</stock_quantity>
<weight>0</weight>
<length>n/a</length>
<width>n/a</width>
<height>n/a</height>
<colour>n/a</colour>
<size>n/a</size>
<material>n/a</material>
<pattern>n/a</pattern>
</product>
```

[/EDIT2]

Comment: Have you opened the XML file you saved in an editor or browser to check the content?

Comment: @techiServices, yes, I did open it and check. everything is in order. In fact the piece that I put on the linked question was copy/paste from that file.

Comment: Ah, ok missed that.  Can you post a stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: @techiServices, added all relevant information.

Comment: 'at com.skylite.irabwah.Communicator.loadProductPicture(Communicator.java:88)' is the line that causes a NPE, so either you are passing in NULL or using a NULL.  Set a breakpoint on the first line of the function and step through checking for the variable that's NULL.

Comment: @techiServices, well this line is "finally { stream.close()" where "{" is located. No wonder as as I explained in the original post the file name cuts off. And so the "stream" object can not be constructed.

Comment: so are you saying 'stream' is NULL? basically you are trying to do something with a variable that is NULL in Communicator.loadProductPicture.

Comment: @techiServices, flow goes, like this: I'm getting main xml file part of it is referenced in the linked post and parse it. during parsing I'm reading the bitmap that is located remotely. My guess is that the stream from this xml is being cut off and so I'm not able to properly construct the object second time.

Comment: hi Igor, it is this line that is causing the problem `stream = new URL( url ).openStream();`.  it is probably causing an exception or at the least returning NULL.  Since `finally` is always called you are causing an unhandled exception when trying to `close` `stream` but stream is null. Use `if (stream != null) { stream.close }`.  It will stop the NPE.

Comment: @techiServices, Well it will stop the exception, but the program will not work nevertheless. Any idea how to increase the buffer length of the stream?

Comment: you should not need to increase any buffers.  use a consistent method for retrieving streams.  at the moment you use `InputStream is = responce.getEntity().getContent();` to get XML and `stream = new URL( url ).openStream();` to get Bitmap.  with the XML get stream code you at least have the opportunity to get a http response code and it does get the XML.

Comment: what i would do is connect to the http uri, check status code, get `Inputstream` wrapped in a `BufferedInputStream`, write stream data to a byte array, close stream. You can then process the byte array without http connection being open.

Comment: Igor, I am going to vote to close the question since the solution will be specific to your case only.  All the best.

Comment: @techiServices, I understand what u saying buthere is the deal. First request I'm retrieving XML file which for some unknown reason is cut off at the same place (~2K in size being read). This in tern will cause the second request to the server fail as the line will be incomplete: "abc/def" instead of "abc/def/myimage.jpg". And then there is a lot of information that is lost.

Comment: However, I can store the XML in a local file and parse this local file so this issue is worked around and not resolved. It just takes time to store the stream in a file.

Comment: @techiServices, I also added sample xml file that I am suppose to get. The code that fails read the stream until the middle of the second product image_url tag: "http://irabwah.com/image/data/Mas", leaving behind the rest of the file name and a whole lot of other information. Hence my question about increasing the size for the stream. Thank you.